# My code segment sometimes runs, and sometimes it throws and error. Is there a problem with my memory programming? What's the deal with the code?

Tags: c++

first file. now we are in "Position.h"

```
struct Position{
  int digit;
  int possible[9];
  int logicalSize;
  bool isPermanent;

  Position* next;
  Position* last;
};

typedef Position* Positionptr;
```

next file. now we are in "Board.h"

```
#include "Position.h"
class Board{
  private:
    //maybe use an array of structures
    Position elements[81];
    bool membership(int arr[], int digit);



  public:
    void print();
    Board(int input[]);

    int* getRow(int row);
    int* getColumn(int col);

    //make private
    void makePossibleList(int row, int col);

    void solve();

};
```

next file. now we are in "Board.cpp"

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Board::Board(int input[]){
  for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++){

    Position temp;
    temp.digit = input[i];
    //possible is already initialized
    if(input[i] == 0){
      temp.isPermanent = false;
    }
    else{
      //this position is set and cannot be changed
      temp.isPermanent = true;
    }

    elements[i] = temp;
  }
}

void Board::print(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    int* arr = getRow(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  //confirmed that it can print backwards
}

bool Board::membership(int arr[], int digit){
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(arr[i] == digit) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void Board::makePossibleList(int row, int col){

  Position temp = elements[row*9 + col];

  int* tempRow = getRow(row);
  int* tempColumn = getColumn(col);

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    if(membership(tempRow, i)){
      continue;
    }
    else if(membership(tempColumn, i)){
      continue;
    }
    else{
      temp.possible[temp.logicalSize] = i;
      temp.logicalSize++;
    }
  }

  //find the possible values for this position
}

int* Board::getRow(int row){
  int* temp = new int[9];
  for(int i = (row*9); i < (9*(row+1)); i++){
    temp[i-row*9] = elements[i].digit;
  }
  return temp;
}

int* Board::getColumn(int col){
  int* temp = new int[9];
  for(int i = 0; i < 81; i+= 9){
    temp[((i+1)/9)] = elements[(i+col)].digit;
  }
  return temp;
}

void Board::solve(){
  cout << "here";
  for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++){
    Position temp = elements[i];

    if(temp.isPermanent){
      continue;
    }
    ///*
    else{
      int row = i/9;
      int col = i%9;
      makePossibleList(row, col);
      if(temp.logicalSize == 0){
        break; //something messed up
      }



      else{


        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
          cout << temp.possible[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;



        //use the end of possible list value
        temp.digit = temp.possible[temp.logicalSize-1];
        temp.digit = *(temp.possible + temp.logicalSize-1);
        temp.logicalSize--;
        //logicalSize will equal 0 if we use up the last one!!


      }




    }
    //*/

  }
  cout << "here";
  //either the loop broke because something is wrong
  //     or the loop finished and the puzzle is solved
  print();

}
```

//In the main.cpp file I run the driver code

//everything from above comes from the Board.h file
next file. we are now in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!\n";

  int puzzle[] =       {0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 6, 0, 
                        0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 2, 
                        0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
                        0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
                        0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 9, 0, 
                        9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 0, 7, 0, 
                        0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
                        8, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
                        0, 9, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0};
  Board x = Board(puzzle);
  //x.print();
  cout << "here";
  x.solve();
}
```

I cannot understand why my code segment does not run properly ALL the time. It will run once, ill hit run one more time, and then it wont run. I am using the repl.it compiler. I have an inkling that the solve() method is the root of the problem as I tested other parts of the program before I wrote the solve() method. Is there anything wrong with my memory allocation? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use the debugger to step through the code in `solve()`? Which line causes the error to happen?

Comment: Debugger almost instantly showed that `temp.logicalSize` climbed up to <expletive deleted> big and shot off the end of ` temp.possible`. Debuggers are awesome.

Comment: A few seconds more work showed that `logicalSize` doesn't seem to be initialized. Use the debugger. The time you waste not using it time you'll never get back.

Comment: `Position temp;` -- This is unsafe to use, since all of the member variables are uninitialized.  Not only is `logicalSize` starting out with a value equal to who-knows-what, all of your other members start out the same way.  Initialize your member variables (there are multiple ways to do this) before utilizing `temp`.

Comment: Your code segment is _huge_. Would it be possible to cut it down to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

C++ code that sometimes works, is a strong indication for [Undefined Behavior](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213).

So, as a first step I ran this through [UBSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html)

Here is the result on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/jqpubW

```
example.cpp:60:12: runtime error: member call on address 0x00000044a300 which does not point to an object of type 'std::basic_ostream<char>'
0x00000044a300: note: object has invalid vptr
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior example.cpp:60:12 in 
example.cpp:62:10: runtime error: member call on address 0x00000044a300 which does not point to an object of type 'std::basic_ostream<char>'
0x00000044a300: note: object has invalid vptr
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior example.cpp:62:10 in
```

These are the highlighted lines:

```cpp
    int* arr = getRow(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

The row returned has not been initialized.

## Memory Sanitizer

You have to fix this, in order to see if more issues exist.

Afterwards, also run this through [Address Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

Let's run it through Memory Sanitizer first (as someone wrote a comment that there's uninitialized memory).

This is on a GCP micro-us-1 instance running "debian-10-buster-v20200210", in case you don't have a Linux machine handy. Just spin up an instance and install `sudo apt install clang`.

```sh
user@micro-us-1:~$ clang++ -fsanitize=memory -g q61003206.cc && ./a.out
Hello World!
==6314==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x4991d4 in Board::makePossibleList(int, int) /home/user/q61003206.cc:89:39
    #1 0x499789 in Board::solve() /home/user/q61003206.cc:125:7
    #2 0x499ce4 in main /home/user/q61003206.cc:164:5
    #3 0x7fcc3fd3609a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2409a)
    #4 0x41f379 in _start (/home/user/a.out+0x41f379)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /home/user/q61003206.cc:89:39 in Board::makePossibleList(int, int)
Exiting
```

This is pointing at `temp.possible` which is not initialized because the default constructor for `Position` does not initialize the `possible` field. The right way to fix this, is to make `possible` a `std::array<int, 9> possible;`. Also, default initialize `Position::logicalSize`.

```cpp
void Board::makePossibleList(int row, int col) {

  Position temp = elements[row * 9 + col];

  int *tempRow = getRow(row);
  int *tempColumn = getColumn(col);

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (membership(tempRow, i)) {
      continue;
    } else if (membership(tempColumn, i)) {
      continue;
    } else {
      // This is the problematic line as highlighted by MSAN
      temp.possible[temp.logicalSize] = i;
      temp.logicalSize++;
    }
  }

  // find the possible values for this position
}
```

## Fix

This is how the `Position` struct looks like afterwards for me:

```cpp
struct Position {
  int digit;
  std::array<int, 9> possible ;  // This should be a vector
  int logicalSize {0};
  bool isPermanent;

  Position *next;
  Position *last;
};
```

This is enough to fix the issue, but you should really do it this way. Default initialize all members, and remove unused members, and use the right container for something which is variable sized (vector).

```cpp
struct Position {
  int digit {-1};
  // logicalSize and possible get combined into one vector that can grow and shrink.
  std::vector<int> possible;
  bool isPermanent {false};

  // These two are unused!
  // Position *next;
  // Position *last;
};
```

Side note, you'll also have to fix this block like so:

```
        // use the end of possible list value
        temp.digit = temp.possible[temp.logicalSize - 1];
        // temp.digit = *(temp.possible + temp.logicalSize - 1);
        temp.digit = temp.possible.at(temp.logicalSize - 1);
        temp.logicalSize--;
```

## Code Review

I suggest that you post this on Code Review SE.

Some items of note, but not exclusive:

- Comment your data structures. For example, what is the meaning of the `int possible[9]` field in `Position`.
- Use modern C++.

  - Use containers as provided by the STL. In your case this means a lot of `std::array`.
  - Many fewer raw pointers, and definitely no using of `new`.
  - Do not use `using namespace std`.

Comment: *"You are not allowed to iterate through a int pointer in C++."* What?